# SQL - how to generate distinct pairs from a single column

Tags: sql, select

Could anyone help with how to take a single column:

```
ID
1
2
3
4
```

and show all possible distinct pairings in 2 columns:

```
ID ID
1  2
1  3
1  4
2  3
2  4
3  4
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the column on itself and arbitrarily decide that the left hand side will always be smaller than the right hand side (as the example shows):

```
SELECT t1.col, t2.col
FROM   mytable t1
JOIN   mytable t2 ON t1.col < t2.col
```

Answer (score 1):

do self join

```
select t.id,t2.id from t t1 join t t2 on t.id<t1.id
```

Comment: Nope. It will produce `1,1` and `4,3` anong others.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple Cartesian product should do

```
select distinct a.id as id_a, b.id as id_b
from test a, test b
where a.id<b.id;
```